# How can I extend the powershell help synopsis? They get cut off at the ends with

Tags: powershell

when I use help in PowerShell to see some commands, it cuts off the end of the synopsis so I cant see at a glance what each command does. I tried adding the -full parameter, but this makes no difference. Have attached image to show what I mean.

[image]

[image]

Anything I can do to display the synopsis in full?

After some playing with formatting in powershell, I found the best option to export the contents to xlm and view in excel. Thank you for the suggestions!

help *event* | Export-CSV c:\Lists.csv

[Excel output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1iNa.png)

Comment: Because of the non-fixed-width font it may appear to be arbitrarily cut off, but it probably isn’t. How wide is your terminal window?

Comment: You can resolve this by decreasing the size of the font or increasing the width of the console.  The "..." are an indication the string is being compressed. "..." have a name in formal writing, their name, simply escapes me. Piping the results and formatting them might get you what you want.

Comment: Pretty large! lots of free space, edited to show.

Comment: Thank you, I'll pipe it over somewhere more readable.

Comment: I was thinking of ellipsis by the way.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735275/change-powershell-script-to-output-without-ellipses) is a discussion on that subject.  In my testing it didn't seem to make a difference, you do indeed need to format the table, otherwise PowerShell will make some assumptions.

Comment: Its still quite ugly. Wonder can I export this into excel format?

Comment: This should be reopened. I found the solution and its definitely not what the duplicate says. I'd like to explain this a bit further too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some playing with formatting in powershell, I found the best option to export the contents to xlm and view in excel. Thank you for the suggestions and information, was helpful!

help event | Export-CSV c:\Lists.csv

Excel output

Credit to LPCHIP in the comments! : get-help -full event | fl Name, Category, Module, Synopsis

is another and best solution for viewing in the powershell console itself.

Comment: `help event | out-file c:\output.txt` is probably the exact same.

Comment: Sadly no, it still shows the ... ellipsis same as the powershell window! Seems the excel is the best worst solution!

Comment: interesting....

Comment: I found the answer. Too bad this was locked, as this is a specific problem with a specific answer. Here is the command you want: `get-help -full event | fl Name, Category, Module, Synopsis  `

Comment: perfect! Thank you. I tried to credit you, but could only edit my answer to point to yours. Much appreciated

Comment: I found out that `get-help event | fl` is already enough, except that now, you get way too much info. Apparently the get-help is different from help and as such the | fl doesn't work on help, but it does work on get-help.

Comment: I think help is just a function which points to get-help and not an alias. Yea its handy though to know you can add specifics so if you just need to know only the module etc, thank you again.

Comment: I don't see a downvote on my end for either question and answer.

Comment: Ah, maybe im thinking reddit where it starts you on 1. My faith is restored.